# rdlc report page header field values not displaying when the sub report page breaks happens in body section

Tags: c#-3.0, rdlc

I got the field values of report header section by using the "=ReportItems!txtbox_body1.Value" from the report body section which I am binding through dataset value. And I have a subreport as well in report body. Now the problem is the page header values are comming in first page, but not in second page when the page break happens by the sub-report.

Please advise if anyone has any solution for this with sample coding.

Thanks,